# How to avoid changing the backdrop of my neighbor's chromecast?

Tags: chromecast

I'd like to set my Chromecast's backdrop up with some custom pictures, but any attempt to do this also changes the pictures on my neighbor's Chromecast. We don't have a problem here - we had a good laugh about it - but is there any way to change the backdrop of my Chromecast and not theirs? The two seem to be linked in the Android app.

Comment: Did you ever connect your android app to your neighbors chromecast? It displays a code on screen to connect. you need to know that code to connect. Can you unregister devices from the app/

Comment: No, I never did that.